# Hibernate attribute return true instead of false

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

I need your help because I am using spring and the frameworks hibernate and thymeleaf to use java in html.
I have an object on my model which is `ActivityField.java`, which has a boolean attribute called required.
When I am using it, as `myInstance.isRequired()`, the code returns me true instead of false (which is the value in the database)

I have searched a lot, and I do not understand why. I already add this problem before, it was due to the `DISTINCT` in Query of the repository. However, this time there is no query.

Here is an extract of my html using thymeleaf.
My table loop on each element of a datalist of ActivityField object, and I display attributes in the lines.
[image]

Here is my table where you can see the column "Obligatoire" Which is "required", 2 of 4 items are marked has required. But in the database no one is.
[image]

Here is the database screenshot

[image]

I tried to print each element in the back office logs to see if the problem is from the IHM or from the server, and it seems to be from the server. has you can see below.

[image]

I also tried to create a function in the service/repository to find all elements associated, but it returns the same result.

[image]

When I'm using my buttons, the attribute change well in the database, but when I'm reloading the page, it always come has true.

If someone else has already seen this problem please help me. If you need more information I will do my best to be as clear as possible.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Show how required is defined and mapped in your entity class.

Comment: it is just `private boolean required;`

Comment: Since your controller outputs the correct values, but the view gets it wrong, I doubt this has anything to do with Hibernate, and is rather a frontend issue.

Comment: No has you can see, the controller outputs a wrong value because it returns in the console a true instead of the false present in the database.

Comment: I find a solution by coding a function in the repository that return just the value of required instead of object. And it works fine, but I do not understand why the getter returns it wrong.